# change default font in semantic-ui with @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, semantic-ui

i want to change semantic-ui default font with @font-face but no matter...

i tried change in less file(site.variables) but I do not know how change it

i tried add my font with other custom css file but it not work

```
@font-face  {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot'); 
    src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot?#') format('eot'),    
          url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff');
}
body{
    font-family: 'fontname';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact changes you made to the site.variables file (as well as which *site.variables* exactly you changed, as there is more than one in Semantic UI)?

Comment: there is site.varibles: [Link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/953ecaa80d5083f0be71) , i try change this default font @fstanis

Answer (score 7):

I know two ways to change font-face, using google fonts or offline fonts:

#### Using google fonts:

1. We need to have the resources of **Semantic UI**, you can get here:

https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

2. It is required to create the file `site.variables` in `semantic/src/site/globals/`
3. We search for the source that we like most at https://fonts.google.com/ and copy the name.
4. In the file `site.variables` we add the name of the font to the variable `@fontName` as follows:

```
/*******************************
     User Global Variables
*******************************/

@fontName          : 'Roboto';
```

5. Finally we execute the command `glup build-css`, the changes will be reflected in the file semantic `/dist/semantic.css`

---

#### Using offline fonts

1. We need to have the resources of **Semantic UI**, you can get here:

https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

2. It is required to create the file `site.variables` in `semantic/src/site/globals/`
3. In the file `site.variables` we add the variable `@importGoogleFonts` with the value `false`;

```
/*******************************
     User Global Variables
*******************************/

@importGoogleFonts : false;
@fontName          : 'fontname';
```

4. It is required to create the file `site.overrides` in `semantic/src/site/globals /`
5. In the file `site.overrides` we add our `font-face`

```
/*******************************
         Site Overrides
*******************************/

@font-face  {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot'); 
    src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot?#') format('eot'),    
          url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff');
}
```

6. Finally we execute the command `gulp build-css`, the changes will be reflected in the file semantic `/dist/semantic.css`

---

This video maked by [@Aditya Giri](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChTZNcO1p-1JT0LfM0-EPPQ) explain how change font family from google fonts

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSdKA-tZEbg

In the next issue [@jlukic](https://github.com/jlukic)  explain how use offline fonts

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1521

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Add the following to a .css file:

  ```
  @font-face  {
      font-family: 'fontname';
      src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot'); 
      src:url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.eot?#') format('eot'),    
          url('themes/basic/assets/fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff');
  }
  ```
- Import the above code before semantic's site.min.css
- Change the @fontName to 'fontname'
- @importGoogleFonts should be false since you don't want to import any fonts from Google

By default the above will applied to body

Comment: You shouldn't add anything in .css file when you are working with semantic-ui!

Comment: Shouldn't you? I'm using styling components with semantic-ui, and there's nothing wrong in modifying semantic-ui behavior from there. Another possibility is to develop a new theme for semantic-ui, but depending on the case it may be overkill, and you'd destroy the benefits of styling within the same component

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I just wanted to add one thing.

Because all Semantic UI elements inherits the `ui` class you could do it like this:

```
.ui {
   font-family: 'fontname' !important;
}
```

Not so elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complicated solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208399/2374997 but if you want a simpler approach you could follow this example:

```
/*In your .css file, loaded after semantic.min.css*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google Link:

1. Add to index.html google link. For example:

`<linkhref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Glitch&display=swap"rel="stylesheet"/>`

2. Add Font in semantic.ui> site> globals > site.variables. For example:

   ```
   /*******************************
         User Global Variables
    *******************************/
    /*--FONTS--*/

    @pageFont: Rubik Glitch;
   ```