# How to change font on Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to change the default 'Lato' font in Semantic UI but I haven't succeded.

I tried defining the new font in site.variables (/src/site/globals)

```
@headerFont        : 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
@pageFont          : 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
@googleFontFamily  : 'Open+Sans:400italic,400|Oswald:400,700';
```

I also tried in site/components/site.css, in site.overrides file and finally on src/themes/default/globals/site.variables. No luck in any of those locations and I don't understand the documentation example. Maybe I installed Semantic in the wrong way.

Where am I suppose to define the new font? thanks

Comment: Check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937610/change-default-font-in-semantic-ui-with-font-face

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild the package after making the changes?

```
gulp build
```

You could also duplicate the default theme, rename it and make your edits in there to keep things a little cleaner IMO. If you go this route though, you'll need to make sure you update your theme.config file to reflect the theme you want the compiler to build when you run the command above.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the "Simpler Setup" now, the lightweight package of Semantic UI and it's working fine.